# Hibernate - entity design with multiple dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently working on an API and came across the following design.

[image: erm]

```
    // not mandatory
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
```

Actually, a telephone number should belong to a company, person or a contact form. However, this is logically not possible with the current design. So there is a small validation at the service level to make sure that there is always at least one dependency.

Now I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this. Because theoretically something can always go wrong and dependencies can be lost and the data would still be valid according to today's status.

I thought about creating a separate phone number object for each entity that inherits from the phone number. But somehow I don't really like the solution, but I think it's better than the previous one. What I don't like so much is that a lot more objects are created which also contain inheritance.

[image: new erm]

Is the new approach ok or how do you solve such problems?

Comment: What speciality is there about the phone number for it to be in it's own entity? Just wondering cause from first thought I don't really think thats needed

Comment: You can add a `constraint` on the database to ensure Phone Number is always referenced to another table.

Comment: A phone number itself shouldn't justify a database table. It's ok if you store metadata about the number or if you actually mean a "phone contract" (though contact form suggests otherwise). If not, consider the effects on transaction management that an additional table brings.

Comment: @Nico Sorry for the late answer. Um there is a phone type and a numbering of the numbers, but don't ask me why.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am aware of that. I'm in the process of optimizing the whole construct because it contains a lot of unnecessary stuff. Why it is an object I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Another option is to add a `PhoneNumberType` to the PhoneNumber table.

In any case you should ensure the table has appropriate constraints added so that a PhoneNumber must relate to a table.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer! That's what you like to hear. I also thought it was more important that the data is always 100% correct. We currently do this with the type simply via a string, but that's true, you should also replace that with an enum to further reduce the susceptibility to errors.